# Changing the date from 2012-01-31 to 31-01-2012 in sed/awk/grep

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to swap the digits format from 2012-01-31 to 31-01-2012. Looked for lots of pages on Stack Overflow and found nothing. Can someone help me with this task?

I tried this so far:

```
echo 2012-01-31 | sed 's/^([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/\3-\2-\1/'
```

Comment: How are you printing the date currently? Seeing your current code would help.

Comment: echo 2012-01-31 | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/\3-\2-\1/'

Comment: Close:  `sed 's/^([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/\\3-\\2-\\1/' ` works for me. But I have a dozen answers here where I tell peope *never* to parse date in a regexp.  You can even use GNU date for this.  Parse as a _date_, then format as a _date_.

Comment: For me it does nothing. Still writing the same format which I'm having on input.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel You need `-E` (or `-r`) and have to not double escape backslashes in the replacement string for your command to work.

Comment: @SergeiKhokhryakov All you need to change is either add `-E`/`-r` or escape the parentheses for the capture groups.

Comment: Sure thing, I forgot about -E. Thank you!

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks, but it does in fact work here on standard Linux / GNU sed and has for years.  No magic.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel At the danger of coming across as a pedant, I don't think it does - see it [here on ideone](https://ideone.com/KP0g22).

Comment: You are correct, I guess I was rushing and didn't notice.  As I said in earlier comments, I tend to recommend date parsers anyway.  But here, for completeness, `sed -r ...` works as you said.  Thanks for being diligent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct version of what you were trying to do is following.

```
echo '2012-01-31' | sed -E 's/^([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/\3-\2-\1/'
```

or without extended regex,

```
echo '2012-01-31' | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/\3-\2-\1/'
```

If you know the input is correct, but just need to reorder them, following will be more simple.

```
echo '2012-01-31' | sed -E 's/^(....)-(..)-(..)/\3-\2-\1/'
```

With pure bash,

```
a='2012-01-31'
[[ "$a" =~ (....)-(..)-(..) ]] || exit                          # exit if regex match failed
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) to first read and then format the output:

```
date -d 2012-01-31 +%d-%m-%Y
```

Comment: That solves my problem, but can you do this with the regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='4 1 2 1 2' '{ print $5, $3, $1 }' OFS=-
```

With any awk:

```
awk '{ print $3, $2, $1 }' FS=- OFS=-
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. This command prints the numbers without "-" between each digit. Is there any solution? I know what OFS does but for me, it outputs nothing

Comment: @SergeiKhokhryakov: did you try the second version?

Comment: sure, maybe I forgot the commas betwen each $'s and thats the problem, but I did this code: awk { print $3 "-" $2 "-" $1}' FS=-. My bad thought, thank you!